Using OneDrive/SharePoint File Handler. OneDrive UI changed and now my "newFile" handler is not on the new "Add New" menu
I have a File Handler (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online) set up for my application.  It was working for months with both SharePoint and OneDrive.  In August of 2023, OneDrive UI changed, and the "New" button above the documents list was removed;  the "New" button is where my file handler was causing there to be a menu item for my application).   OneDrive now has an "Add New" button along the left edge of the UI.... all the entries that had been in the (documents list) "New" menu are moved there, but my File Handler entry is not present.
My File Handler is still there for OneDrive.  Files with my extension still are shown with my icon;  the "edit" and "preview" urls in my File Handler still appear in OneDrive's menu, and work when used.  In addition, the "addFile" File Handler option that had been working is still working for SharePoint.
Trying to get Microsoft to look at this as a bug has been a nightmare.   I'm hoping there's just a new (yet to be documented) "action" that has been added to the File Handler specification that I can use.
